# Pre-processing code for RMQ Problem. What does it do?

Tags: algorithm

This is taken from TopCoder's Algorithm page - section on "Trivial algorithms for RMQ"
Supposedly a pre-processing function for calculating RMQ on the A array.

```
 void process1(int M[MAXN][MAXN], int A[MAXN], int N)
  {
      int i, j;
      for (i =0; i < N; i++)
          M[i][i] = i;
      for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
          for (j = i + 1; j < N; j++)
              if (A[M[i][j - 1]] < A[j])
                  M[i][j] = M[i][j - 1];
              else
                  M[i][j] = j;
  }
```

But I don't see how the M 2D array generated would be helpful in calculating the RMQ, what am I not getting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Hint*

The array `A[]` contains the sequence of elements that you calculate the RMQ for. The array `M[][]` contains answers for every query of type "What is the minimum element in range a..b?" into `M[a][b]`.

*Full answer*

This way, you can look up the answer to any query on in constant time by looking at the respective element inside `M[][]`.

The way it is calculated is as follows:

- The first for-loop iterates over all elements and assigns the minimum of the range `i..i` to `i`. This is because the minimum of one-element-range is just that element.
- The nested loops then calculate the RMQ answers for the other ranges `i..k` for all `k > i`. This is done by extending the already-calculated range that starts at `i` by one element at a time.

Comment: Got it! If A = { 4,2,3,1 } The table looks like
M[0]: {0,1,1,3} M[1]: {"",1,1,3} M[2]: {"","",2,3} M[3]: {"","","",3}  And to answer for example between 0 and 2, just look up M[0][2] = 1. Meaning A[1] = 2 is the minimum in that range!